# Error: Can't push, pull, merge or clone in github

Tags: git, github

While I'm trying to push, pull or merge the local to github repo I'm getting some issues. I even tried to clone the new local repo but that is also giving problem. Can anyone please help me in this matter.

Executed command result:

```
$ git push
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection timed out while accessing https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Comment: Was this working at some point and then stopped working? Or has it never worked? "Connection timed out" sounds like it could be your internet connection, github's servers not responding, or ssh being blocked perhaps. status.github.com looks like they aren't having any problems, though, and you appear to be connected to the internet since you asked this question... what output do you get if you [follow this test procedure](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-4-test-everything-out)?

Comment: I got the similar problem after I rollbacked to the previous commit. Dont think its internet problem, can Anyone suggest the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have internet connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a firewall issue. Try disabling the firewall, connecting using a different network, or asking your firewall administrator to let you access github somehow, maybe using an ssh jump host.